# Azure SQL: How can I share replicated db access with specific users?

Tags: replication, azure-sql-database, users

I have 2 Azure SQL instances :

- `db-main` which is my main DB, containing both `my-db` and `master` databases.
- `db-replica` which contains a readonly replica `my-db@db-main`

I have currently a user `my-db-admin` having `db_owner` role on `my-db` database.

I would like to create a **specific login** (and, if needed, a linked user to this login) with access to only the replicated `my-db@db-replica` database.

I tried multiple options which are not working so far :

- **Option 1**

I tried creating a login on `db-main` + a user on `my-db@db-main` + granting access to my the database... which is then replicated to `my-db@db-replica` :

```
-- To execute on db-main :
use master;
CREATE LOGIN [my-replica-login] WITH PASSWORD='abc';

use my-db;
CREATE USER [my-replica-user] for login [my-replica-login];
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'my-replica-user';
```

I was then able to connect to `db-replica` with `my-replica-user` but :

- for some (unknown) reasons it was not having access to `my-db@db-replica`

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The server principal "my-replica-user" is not able to access the database "my-db" under the current security context.
Cannot open database "my-db" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'my-replica-user'.
```

- even if this was the case, I would have preferred to not share credentials between `db-main` and `db-replica`
- **Option 2**

I tried creating `my-replica-user` only on `db-replica` ... but given that this DB is readonly, it was not possible.

Do you have any idea on how I may sort this out ?